# URL rewritemap apache

Tags: apache, rewritemap

I am pretty new to programming, and have encountered the following problem. Please kindly advise me.

I have a website with a URL like `www.mysite.com/products.php?cid=3` 
where the value of the parameter `cid` (3 here) is generated from a backend database, and can be a number from 1 to 3.

I would like Apache to rewrite the URL, so that:

`www.mysite.com/nike` will redirect to `www.mysite.com/products.php?cid=1`

`www.mysite.com/reebok` will redirect to `www.mysite.com/products.php?cid=2`

`www.mysite.com/kswiss` will redirect to `www.mysite.com/products.php?cid=3`

etc...

I have a text file named **category.txt** under the root directory with the following content:

```
nike 1 
reebok 2 
kwiss 3
```

and .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
rewritemap categorymap txt:/image/categorymap.txt 
RewriteRule ^(.*) /products.php?cid=${categorymap:$1|NOTFOUND} [PT] 
</IfModule>
```

This, however does not work, please advise me,

Comment: Please add details about what does happen

Answer (score 0):

The [`RewriteMap` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) can only be used in either server or vhost config. You'll need to define it there. If you don't have access to either server or vhost config, then you'll just need to enumerate all of those into individual rewrite directives like:

```
RewriteRule ^nike$ /products.php?cid=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^reebok$ /products.php?cid=2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^kswiss$ /products.php?cid=3 [L,QSA]
```