# apache mod_rewritemap virtual host file

Tags: apache, virtual, host, rewritemap

Hi I am very  new to all these. my website need rewrite url. I joined godaddy linux based.

i want to use the rewrite map function. and trying to write the syntex for this purpose

However i just found that the code has to be put in virtual host file in apache configuration, and rewriteMap only works if you have access in httpd.conf and virtual host.

i have no idea on these. where can i find the 'virtual host file', and the httpd.conf?

can someone give clear procedure for me

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Godaddy, it is unlikely you'll have access to any of these things. You can either contact Godaddy's customer support, or follow my work-around [in the last question that you asked about RewriteMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962196/url-rewritemap-apache/11962247#11962247).

Answer (score 0):

With Go Daddy shared hosting you will not have access to the virtual host configuration.